# Iron router: Error: Couldn't find a template named "/" or "". Are you sure you defined it?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-0.9.4

I have trouble setting up a simple iron:router example: ([docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), [sample app](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/tree/devel/examples/basic))

```
meteor create testapp
cd testapp
```

**home.html**:

```
<template name="Home">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  home
</template>
```

**router.js**:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home'); // Also tried 'home'
});
```

Starting the server:

```
meteor
```

Then I get (client side):

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: Couldn't find a template named "/" or "". Are you sure you defined it?
    at null._render (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_dynamic-template.js?32038885cb1dad7957291ffebfffcb7f8cd57d20:239:17)
    at doRender (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?88aac5d3c26b7576ac55bb3afc5324f465757709:1853:25)
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Note: I get the exact same error if I clone [the example application](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/tree/devel/examples/basic) (basic.html and basic.js).

```
meteor list
autopublish      1.0.1  Publish the entire database to all clients
insecure         1.0.1  Allow all database writes by default
iron:router      0.9.4  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform  1.1.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
```

Also:

```
meteor --version
Meteor 0.9.4 <- Why all standard packages and meteor platform are > 1.0 and this is 0.9.4 ?
```

Comment: You are using the wrong version of iron router, remove it and add `iron:router@1.0.0-pre4` instead.

Comment: @saimeunt Thanks a lot, that was the problem. It really should be more obvious when you use a package that is not compatible with the current version of meteor.

Comment: It's actually iron router that does not make obvious that its examples are designed with the 1.0.0 pre-release, not iron:router@0.9.4.

Comment: @saimeunt  make this an answer, I had the same problem and need to shower you in upvotes.

Comment: Added clarifications about these `iron:router` versioning issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there are two versions of `iron:router`.

- `iron:router@0.9.4` is the one added by default when you type `meteor add iron:router`, this version is the latest in the "legacy" branch of `iron:router` that came up more than one year ago, it's the one that everyone is probably still using, although they should definitely update to...
- `iron:router@1.0.0-preX` with `X = 4` as of 20/10/2014, which is a complete rewrite of the package intended to be backward compatible, but introducing a new, nicer and polished API. This version will likely be set as default when meteor hits 1.0.0 later this year. The problem is that github page of `iron:router` shows this particular branch (`1.0.0-pre4`) along with examples that people believe are usable with `0.9.4`.

This means that you are most likely using the wrong version of iron router, remove it with `meteor remove iron:router` and `meteor add iron:router@1.0.0-pre4` instead.

Recommended reading to learn about the latest `iron:router` syntax :

http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/

Sometimes the guide is not completely up-to-date with the pre-release version, if you want to keep up with the latest stuff take a look at github issues.

Comment: We have the same issue, but on `iron:router@1.0.12`, and only on mobile
any idea?