# iron:router - "Couldn't find a template named 'loading'..."

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm getting this weird error:

"**Couldn't find a template named 'loading' or 'loading'. Are you sure you defined it?**"

Just like [Iron router: Error: Couldn't find a template named "/" or "". Are you sure you defined it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450293/iron-router-error-couldnt-find-a-template-named-or-are-you-sure-you-d)

Unfortunately, the answer there was not very helpful (probably because it's old and I'm using version 1.0.7 already).

Here's the iron configuration javascript:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); }
});

Router.route('/', {name: 'postsList'});
```

Any hint on this? ^_^

Comment: and you have a file containing <template name="loading">...</template> which is accessible by the client?

Comment: yah.. turns out I somehow skipped this part of the tutorial ! and it is really a missing template file. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a great StackOverflow start.. I'm following "Discover Meteor" book and somehow I skipped the very next part where the actual spinner is added..

Adding the following code solved my problem:

```
<template name="loading">
    {{>spinner}}
</template>
```

Guess I'll need to manage my fast-reading skills, sorry for that.